Dimension Error found in bnlearn package application
This question has been asked before see here but not adequately answered.
Here's my code
library(bnlearn)
cpt_A <- matrix(c(0.8, 0.2), ncol = 2,
                     dimnames = list(NULL, c("True", "False")))
cpt_B <- matrix(c(0.2, 0.8), nrow = 1, ncol = 2,
                   dimnames = list(NULL, c("True", "False")))
cpt_C <- array(c(0.9, 0.6, 0.01, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.99, 0.9),
                      dim = c(2,2,2),
                      dimnames = list(A = c("True", "False"),
                                      B = c("True", "False"),
                                      C = c("True", "False")
                      )
)
net_C <- model2network("[A][B][C|A:B]")
fit_C <- custom.fit(net_C, list(A = cpt_A, 
                                B = cpt_B, 
                                C = cpt_C))

which returns the following error,
Error in check.dnode.rvalue.vs.parents(node, new = dist[[node]], parents = fitted[node.parents]) : 
  wrong dimensions for node C.

Can anyone provide an answer but with an explanation particularly with respect to debugging if this happens again?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69508863/bnlearn-error-wrong-number-of-conditional-probability-distributions/69517806#69517806 ; particularly point three.  (along the lines of cpt_C <- array( c(0.9, 0.1, 0.6, 0.4, 0.99, 0.01, 0.1, 0.9), dim = c(2,2,2),dimnames = list(C = c("True", "False"),A = c("True", "False"),B = c("True", "False"))) )

thanks for the steer ... can you elaborate on the point you made or offer any more help?  Should I completely unpack everything or is there something simple that I'm missing?

In your example, cpt_C holds the conditional prbabilities of a child node where the probabilies are of node C given A and B. The dimension names of cpt_C (and the other provided conditional probabilities) should be the same as given in custom.fit. cpt_C, in your post, has the node name C in the third / last dimension.It needs to be provided in the first. The probabilities should then sum to one in each column / across the rows, for each entry of the array.. Having a look at the CPT's of m = bn.fit(n<-hc(learning.test), learning.test); plot(n) ; m may help.
